# How to delete file only if subdirectory with same name exists in Windows

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, directory

Usually I extract .zip and .rar files in a directory maned as the file without the extension.
E.g.:

```
test.zip
test\
```

Now I'd like to write a Windows batch script that browses all hard drive to delete all .zip or .rar files whenever in the same directory is present a subdirectory with same name of the file without the extension.
But I really don't know where to start.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This simple script is all you need to delete all zip files within C: drive appropriately.

```
@for /r c:\ %%F in (*.zip) do if exist "%%~dpnF\*" del "%%F"
```

You don't even need the script. You can simply run the following from the command line:

```
for /r c:\ %F in (*.zip) do if exist "%~dpnF\*" del "%F"
```